# pagination not working for taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

In functions.php I have a pagination function ..

```
function bd_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

which works flawlessly with my custom post type movies and standard posts.
But when I try to use the function in my taxonomy-genre-mystery.php it doesn't work.

Doesn't work : no errors, keeps displaying page 1 even if another page is selected.

Any help please
Steven

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work".  Are there error messages? What is the actual vs. expected behavior? Include this information in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You use `get_pagenum_link`, a function dedicated to page not archive page.

You need to search around `get_post_type_archive_link` and add manually the page at the end of the url

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'movies' ) . '/' . $i; ?>">Page <?php echo $i; ?></a>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: lost would be an understatement .. as I am new and learning wordpress alone. up until now I have done good but alas I'm stumped. need serious help